# Are all programming languages isomorphic?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-agnostic, isomorphism

For any program written in a certain programming language, is it always possible to compile to a program of equivalent functionality in any other language?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of raw logic, yes; as long as both languages are Turing-complete.

However, if your code uses APIs that are not available in the target language (eg, networking, file systems, 3D acceleration, or threading), then no.  (unless you write a full virtual machine in the target language and build on top of that)

For example, there is no sane way to port shared-memory, multi-threaded code to Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Turing-completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).

While all turing-complete languages have technically equal power, expressing an idea in in one can need orders of magnitude more work than in another.

Also, they might provide different amounts of access to the underlying platform, in the form of APIs or the like.

Which neatly leads to the [turing-tarpit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_tarpit), which means that it can be far too much work to do something in one of them, to the extent that first writing an interpreter for the other language is a win.